# how to find the line number where specific text exists?

Tags: python

This question is about how to find the line number where specific text for example "this is my horse" exists?

text file:

```
this is my name
this is my address
this is my age
this is my horse
this is my book
this is my pc
```

my code:

```
with open ('test.txt', 'r') as infile:
 ?????
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
with open ('test.txt', 'r') as infile:
    data = infile.readlines()
    for line, content in enumerate(data, start=1):
            if content.strip() == 'this is my horse':
                print line
```

which in case of your file will print:

```
4
```

Comment: There was an extra parameter to enumerate introduced in [Python 2.6](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) which is `start`. So in your case, you can set it to 1, and then you can do `print i` instead of `print i + 1` which is easier to read and make more sense

Comment: @Sp. Should you really be reading the whole file with `readlines`? It's probably overkill.

Comment: @thefourtheye The sentence may appears more than once, so you have to.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [enumerate](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) function as it works on anything that is an iterable (which your file is).

```
for line_number, line in enumerate(infile):
  print line_number, line
```

Answer (score 1):

```
s = "this is my horse"
with open ('test.txt', 'r') as infile:
    print next(index for index, line in enumerate(infile, start=1) if line.strip() == s)
```

prints `4`.

Note, that you need to apply `strip()` on lines in order to get rid of new-line chars at the end.